# Where do I put resources for my iOS app in Xcode 7?

Tags: xcode, resources, xcode7

I'm building an iOS app where I need to read in a text file. Where do I put this file in Xcode in order to read it in properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i got ur question right,

Add the file simply drag and drop in xcode: 
[image]

for ex your filename is `sample.txt` you can read it simply using:

```
if let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("sample", ofType: "txt"){
    //reading
    do {
        let text = try NSString(contentsOfFile: path, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
        print(text)
    }
    catch {/* error handling here */}
}
```

Comment: Thanks! This worked perfectly.